# Safari: HTML video controls overwrite window.name

Tags: javascript, html, safari

In Safari 8.0.5 the `controls` attribute for the `video` element will change `window.name` to "webkitendfullscreen". This is critical, since I want to use `window.name` for storing client side data in Safari's private mode (which `localStorage.setItem` won't work in).

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky32zxhe/2/).

Can anybody clarify why this happens? And maybe how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138278) which have been fixed but is currently not shipped in the latest version of Safari.

Unfortunately there is no known workaround.